# show 2 standard deviations on a ggplot2 control chart (in addition to the normal 3)

Tags: r, ggplot2

First I create the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggQC)
set.seed(5555)
Golden_Egg_df <- data.frame(month=1:12, egg_diameter = rnorm(n = 12, mean = 1.5, sd = 0.2))
```

Then I setup the base ggplot.

```
XmR_Plot <- ggplot(Golden_Egg_df, aes(x = month, y = egg_diameter)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line()
```

I can create a simple control chart with the ggQC package, in the following manner.

```
XmR_Plot + stat_QC(method = "XmR")
```

I can facet the control chart to show different levels of standard deviation (in this example, between 1-3).

```
XmR_Plot + stat_qc_violations(method = "XmR")
```

What I want is to be able to see both 2 **and** 3 standard deviations on the same chart, not faceted. My imagined syntax would be

```
XmR_Plot + stat_QC(method = "XmR", stand.dev = c(2, 3))
```

or something like that. But it obviously does not work, how do I get multiple standard deviations to show on 1 chart? It'd look something like this:

[[image]

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the `ggQC` package, but does the `stat_QC` function do something special that you couldn't do by calculating the standard deviation lines manually and then adding `geom_hline()` to your plot manually?

Comment: Yes, the package calculates standard deviation based off average moving range, which is the right way to calculate SD for control charts. So it is best to pull the data from the package, rather than mess with calculating it myself. If curious more info is here on the calculations [link](https://www.qualitydigest.com/inside/six-sigma-column/right-and-wrong-ways-computing-limits.html)

Comment: can you add stat_QC twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend calculating your summary statistics yourself. You'll get a lot more control over the plot!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(5555)
golden.egg.df = data.frame(month=1:12,
                            egg_diameter = rnorm(n = 12,
                                                 mean = 1.5,
                                                 sd = 0.2)
                            )

lines.df = golden.egg.df %>%
  # Calculate all the summary stats
  mutate(mean = mean(egg_diameter),
         sd = sd(egg_diameter),
         plus_one = mean + sd,
         plus_two = mean + 2 * sd,
         plus_three = mean + 3 * sd,
         minus_one = mean - sd,
         minus_two = mean - 2 * sd,
         minus_three = mean - 3 * sd
         ) %>%
  # Remove what we don't want to plot
  select(-month, -egg_diameter, -sd) %>%
  # Filter so the dataframe is now one unique row
  unique() %>% 
  # Make the table tall for plotting
  gather(key = stat,
         value = value) %>%
  # Add a new column which indicates how many SDs a line is from
  # the mean
  mutate(linetype = gsub("[\\s\\S]+?_", "", stat, perl = TRUE))


ggplot(golden.egg.df, 
       aes(x = month, y = egg_diameter)) +
  geom_hline(data = lines.df,
             aes(yintercept = value, linetype = linetype)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: [IMPORTANT] Control chart limits should not use the global standard deviation to calculate limits. See [link](https://www.qualitydigest.com/inside/six-sigma-column/right-and-wrong-ways-computing-limits.html). That said I'll modify the code provided by zlipp to get my ultimate answer, and mark this as the solution. Thank you.